# Convert 8 bit persample to 1 bit per sample image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, libtiff, libtiff.net

I have 8 bit per sample image grayscale. I want to convert it using Libtiff.net:

```
 using (Tiff input = Tiff.Open(fileIn, "r"))
            {
                using (Tiff output = Tiff.Open(fileOut, "w"))
                {
                    for (short page = 0; page < input.NumberOfDirectories(); page++)
                    {
                        input.SetDirectory(page);
                        output.SetDirectory(page);

                        if (input.GetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION)[0].ToInt() == (int)Compression.LZW)
                        {
                            int width = input.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
                            int height = input.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
                            int xres = input.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION)[0].ToInt();
                            int yres = input.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION)[0].ToInt();

                            int samplesPerPixel = input.GetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL)[0].ToInt();
                            int bitsPerSample = input.GetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE)[0].ToInt();
                            int photo = input.GetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC)[0].ToInt();

                            int scanlineSize = input.ScanlineSize();

                            byte[][] buffer = new byte[height][];


                            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
                                buffer[i] = new byte[scanlineSize];
                                input.ReadScanline(buffer[i], i);    
                            }

                            output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, width);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, height);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX4);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 1);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, xres);
                            output.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, yres);

                            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
                                output.WriteScanline(buffer[i], i);

                            output.WriteDirectory();

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

How can i get 8 bit array to 1 bit array image?
I want to do it without converting byte array to bitmap object.
What is the right way?
Thanks

Comment: Umm 1 bit per sample? 1 bit is only 2 values so you want to make every pixel either black or white?

Comment: Simply I want to convert 8 bit grayscale to 1bit monochrome TIFF

Comment: Try googling your problem... lots of hits come up

Comment: @davymartu not **monochromatic** but **binary** image instead ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you go for 1 bit per pixel, note that you get an image with *pure black and white pixels*.

If your source is a grayscale image, you *could* just cap it off at 127, and make all > 127 values '1' and all <= 127 values '0', but to get a more accurate representation it might be useful to look into dithering functions.

For the 127-cutoff way, though, you just make an array of your 8-bit data, which should just have the brightness of each pixel as 0-255 range on each byte. The conversion to black and white is pretty trivial:

```
for (Int32 i=0; i > imagedata.Length; i++)
    imagedata[i] = imagedata[i] > 127 ? 1 : 0;
```

Then, to convert it to an array of 1-bit data, you can use this function. The "stride" is what you got as `scanlineSize` in your code. Note that this function only allocates the minimum needed amount of bytes for the stride.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts given raw image data for a paletted 8-bit image to lower amount of bits per pixel.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data8bit">The eight bit per pixel image data</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width of the image</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height of the image</param>
    /// <param name="newBpp">The new amount of bits per pixel</param>
    /// <param name="stride">Stride used in the original image data. Will be adjusted to the new stride value.</param>
    /// <param name="bigEndian">Values inside a single byte are read from the largest to the smallest bit.</param>
    /// <returns>The image data converted to the requested amount of bits per pixel.</returns>
private static Byte[] ConvertFrom8Bit(Byte[] data8bit, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 bitsLength, Boolean bigEndian)
    {
        if (newBpp > 8)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot convert to bit format greater than 8!", "newBpp");
        if (stride < width)
            throw new ArgumentException("Stride is too small for the given width!", "stride");
        if (data8bit.Length < stride * height)
            throw new ArgumentException("Data given data is too small to contain an 8-bit image of the given dimensions", "data8bit");
    Int32 parts = 8 / bitsLength;
    // Amount of bytes to write per width
    Int32 stride = ((bpp * width) + 7) / 8;
    // Bit mask for reducing original data to actual bits maximum.
    // Should not be needed if data is correct, but eh.
    Int32 bitmask = (1 << bitsLength) - 1;
    Byte[] dataXbit = new Byte[stride * height];
    // Actual conversion porcess.
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (Int32 x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // This will hit the same byte multiple times
            Int32 indexXbit = y * stride + x / parts;
            // This will always get a new index
            Int32 index8bit = y * width + x;
            // Amount of bits to shift the data to get to the current pixel data
            Int32 shift = (x % parts) * bitsLength;
            // Reversed for big-endian
            if (bigEndian)
                shift = 8 - shift - bitsLength;
            // Get data, reduce to bit rate, shift it and store it.
            dataXbit[indexXbit] |= (Byte)((data8bit[index8bit] & bitmask) << shift);
        }
    }
    return dataXbit;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of creating a new 1-bit tiff of the correct dimensions, getting its stride, and writing these resulting bytes into the tiff, line by line, keeping the stride in mind.

Note: I don't know how this is with tiff, but in .Net, 1-bit images *are* paletted, so you might need to give the new image a palette containing that black and white.